# Cast list of Object to list of class' type parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, casting

I'm trying to understanding the different compilation outcome of seemingly analogous code. It appears it is possible to cast a `List<Object>` to a `List<T>` but only if `T` isn't bounded by a concrete class. So given...

```
List<Object> bis = new ArrayList<>();
```

The following compiles in `class Test<T>` as well as in `class Test<T extends CharSequence>` but not in `class Test<T extends BigDecimal>` nor `class Test<T extends BigDecimal & CharSequence>`.

```
List<T> result = (List<T>) bis;
```

So where does the difference come from for `T` bounded with a class type and an interface type?

**Edit**:

Some complete code per request. This compiles with a compiler warning in line 9. It's indeed unsafe as operating on items of `result` as if they were instances of `CharSequence` results in a `ClassCastException`.

```
    public class Sandbox<T extends CharSequence> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sandbox<CharSequence>().foo();
    }

    private void foo() {    
        List<Object> bis = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1));
        List<T> result = (List<T>) bis;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't compile at all:

```
    public class Sandbox<T extends BigDecimal> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sandbox<BigDecimal>().foo();
    }

    private void foo() {    
        List<Object> bis = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1));
        List<T> result = (List<T>) bis;
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Compiler error in line 9: Cannot cast `List<Object>` to `List<T>`.

Comment: Needs more code.  Can you give the exact line(s) that are failing for you?

Comment: It is not type safe to cast `List<Object>` to `List<T>` where `T` can take a value different from `Object`.  Interface type *vs*. class type does not matter.  Whether any given Java compiler diagnoses the problem is a different question.

Comment: The `T extends CharSequence` version does not compile. https://ideone.com/ySVuPr

Comment: OK, I accept the `CharSequence` version doesn't compile universally. Should I then blame Eclipse? ;) Under Eclipse there's only a warning and the program actually runs and only fails if you add code  that attempts to cast an element of the list to the bounding type.

Comment: @gdabski Interesting. In IntelliJ you can switch compilers (I don't know about eclipse), and you are absolutely correct. It compiles using the Eclipse compiler but not using javac. I suspect this is a bug in the Eclipse compiler. It's certainly not correct to cast a `List<Object>` to a `List<T>` where `T extends CharSequence` because `Object` does not implement `CharSequence` and generics are not covariant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this `List<Object> bis = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1));` obviously doesn't compile because `Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1))` will return `List<Integer>`, that's why you get  `Cannot cast List<Object> to List<T>`.

The second case , eclipse absurdly compiles with `T extends CharSequence` but i checked with  a online compiler and it doesn't compile, so quite possibly it's a eclipse bug.

Comment: In fact, `List<Object> bis = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1));` does compile. In earlier versions of java it would only compile with an explicit type argument `List<Object> bis = Arrays.<Object>asList(Integer.valueOf(1));`, but now java has improved type inference and it works either way.

Comment: This is the first answer and mentions the Eclipse compiler as misbehaving, which seems to be the conclusion I was looking for, despite originally believing I don't understand some language intrinsics.

@PaulBoddington thanks as well for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

The key for understanding such behaviour is understanding what **type erasure** actually does. Despite of popular belief that it *removes* type parameters at runtime - it actually doesn't work exactly this way. What it does - it *reduces* them to declared parameter bounds. So anywhere you type `List<T>` where `T` has bounds it is actually reduced to `List<[lower-bound-of-T]>`. And since `Object` is not a `CharSequence`, `List<Object>` cannot be cast to `List<T>` (as it means at least `List<CharSequence>`)

Why this happens? Imagine your `Sandbox` class has method that accepts parameter of type T:

```
public class Sandbox<T extends CharSequence> {
    void bar(T param) {
        //...
    }
}
```

`bar(T)` can accept `T`'s and `T` is anything that extends `CharSequence`, so basically at runtime this effectively works as

```
 void bar(CharSequence param) {
     //...
 }
```

and thus it cannot accept simple `Object`'s. That's why merely existing of non-empty lower parameter bound restricts free casts from `...<Object>`

Moreover, wildcard `?` type parameter can just blow your mind. It says compiler something like "*I have no idea what it is but I'm pretty sure it satisfies all the bounds*". Pretty weird, including that fact, you can cast (almost?) anything to it, so it makes possible

```
  List<Object> bis = Arrays.asList(Integer.valueOf(1));
  List<T> result = (List<T>) (List<?>) bis;
```

So when it comes to design class with generics, you should be very, very careful.